# C# Program Permission Denied when reading files in windows or Users folders

Tags: c#, windows

I have a small program which I am writing to read folder sizes on a drive or in a specific folder.
I am admin user on my pc. But when I run the program it get Permission Denied e.g

```
"Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\tempuser\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data' is denied.
```

I am trying to get all files and folders so that I can calculate full size of the folder. But cant get through this permissions. I have used application manifest and tried "highestAvailable" and "requireAdministrator" both don't seem to do what I want, Can some one shed some light how do I run program so that I get almost true size of the folder?
Here is line of code which I am using

```
sizeInBytes = di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length); //this works great only fails in folders such as above/users/windows etc
```

The above will just throw exception, I used following code to see where exceptions were being thrown

```
var finfoList = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (FileInfo finfo in finfoList) {
    string fname= finfo.Name;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Short version: for debugging, launch Visual Studio as administrator, which isn't the same thing as being a member of the admin group when logged in. For a production app, you would have to give the application admin privileges.

Comment: I thought using manifest file with "requireAdministrator" will give admin rights, if not can you please guide how to give application admin permissions

Comment: You've been given information..Your next step should be to start searching to see if you can find a question already here about that, not to ask another question in a comment. It's OK to need help sometimes, but it's important not to be helpless. You could also do some searching here for *[c#] GetFiles access is denied* to find some posts that would be helpful to you.